# SEVERE: Missing dependency for field : private org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.WadlApplicationContext

Tags: java, web-services, exception, jersey, jax-rs

Can anyone help me .. ? 
i m trying to create a Web Service with JAX-RS but it gives me this exception :

```
SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private    org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.WadlApplicationContext
```

org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.internal.WadlResource.wadlContext

here is my java classe's code:

```
@Path("/DataJson")
public class Ressources {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response test(){

String result = "@Produces(\"application/json\") Output: \n\nF to C Converter Output:     \n\n TEST SUCCESFUL";

return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
}
}
```

--- Web.xml part :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---- the jar used are :

- javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
- javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
- jersey-bundle-1.17.jar
- jersey-client-2.0.jar
- jersey-common-2.0.jar
- jersey-container-servlet.jar
- jersey-multipart-1.14.jar
- jersey-server-2.0.jar
- json.jar
- mimepull-1.9.jar
- asm-3.3.1.jar

----- AND this is exactly the exception i have :

```
 SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private   org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.WadlApplicationContext org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.internal.WadlResource.wadlContext
août 23, 2013 5:30:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Grave: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

août 23, 2013 5:30:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Grave: Exception lors de l'allocation pour la servlet Jersey Web Application
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: I've never seen that exception before, and I've also never seen a RS method which doesn't have an `@Path("/methodPath")` annotation either. Try adding one and seeing if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are missing an init param, where you specify the package where to search for annotated WS resources.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>package.to.your.class</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem not resolve then check whether you have declared public default constructor or not within you package and also add init param tag.
add below in your class.
public Ressources(){
//default constructor`enter code here`
}