# Missing WadlApplicationContext on jersey app trying to use @Valid

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey

I'm having an error that I can't find the solution.

I've a project with jersey 1.19 and I want to validate requests via annotations like @NotNull, @Email, etc.

The app builds ok but when I'm trying to send a request to any method, the console error is:

```
The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:

  SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: 
  private org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.WadlApplicationContext org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.internal.WadlResource.wadlContext

  dic 19, 2015 1:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    ...
```

My pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I tried to put more org.glassfish.jersey dependencies but nothing work for me...

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>MyApp</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyAppWS</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myapp.resources</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyAppWS</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

In addition, the same error happend to user **@seether**
[SEVERE: Missing dependency for field : private org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.WadlApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409088/severe-missing-dependency-for-field-private-org-glassfish-jersey-server-wadl)
I think my web.xml it's ok.

Could anybody help me with this f@#*/%*# error?

Comment: Your Jersey 2.x bean-validation won't work with Jersey 1.x. I Suggest you upgrade to Jersey 2.x.

Comment: There aren't a jersey 2.x version. The last version is 1.19

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet

Comment: See [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet) for new web.xml config

Comment: Just add the one I linked to and remove your 1.x jersey-bundle

Comment: Ok, I did it. But now the error is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

Comment: I have to change the web.xml config servlet-class for another?

Comment: Read all my comments

Comment: Yes but, your comment "See here for new web.xml config" I think the link is bad

Comment: sorry, http://stackoverflow.com/a/27890414/2587435

Comment: Works as expected now. Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 0):

As @peeskillet told me, I had to modify my pom.xml to:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

And modify web.xml servlet-class parameter to:

```
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```