# Creating docker container for java jersey app

Tags: java, docker, jersey

I've been stuck on this for a good bit now and can't find the solution anywhere. I'm writing a java rest service using jersey framework, maven as a package manager hosted on a apache tomcat.

The project works perfectly fine locally. I want to dockerize the application and really struggling. I have the tomcat container up and running and when I go to the root of my application I can see the simple hello text I have. So when I go to `http://xxx:8888/npmanager/` at this point I'm seeing what I expect.

Now when I try to hit any of my endpoints i.e `https://xxx:8888/npmanager/api/XXX` I get a 500 error:

> warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
>   SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.WadlApplicationContext org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.internal.WadlResource.wadlContext

Dockefile:

```
FROM tomcat:8.5.38
ADD ./target/npmanager.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
CMD chmod +x /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

tomcat-dev:
  build: .
  environment:
    TOMCAT_USERNAME: root
    TOMCAT_PASSWORD: root
  ports:
    - "8888:8080"

mysql-dev:
  image: mysql:8.0.2
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_DATABASE: npmanager
  volumes:
    - /mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
  ports:
    - "3308:3306"
```

Comment: Is there any other logs from tomcat service can be added to the question ?

Comment: @MostafaHussein sure. You can find the details log here: https://justpaste.it/4e07q

Comment: you have this error: SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.WadlApplicationContext org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.internal.WadlResource.wadlContext

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SEVERE: Missing dependency for field : private org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.WadlApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409088/severe-missing-dependency-for-field-private-org-glassfish-jersey-server-wadl)

Comment: @MostafaHussein I saw that but I don't see that on my local build. Why is it only showing up on my docker container?

Comment: maybe different versions either java or tomcat or any other dependency ?

Comment: Fair, point. I didn't think of that. Let me check that and see if it's the case.